# Nginx with Cloudflare: Error 525 SSL Handshake failed

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, openssl

I'm trying to deploy my nginx on docker container with Cloudflare.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    image: xxx/panel-nginx:VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: panel_nginx_certs
        target: /etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - panel_nginx
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 180s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  panel_nginx:
    external: true

volumes:
    panel_nginx_certs:
      external: true
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream panel-uwsgi {
    server                      panel_app:8000;
}
server {
    listen                      443 ssl http2;
    listen                      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name                 panel.xxx.com;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/certs/panel.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/certs/panel.key;

    location / {
        include                 uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass              panel-uwsgi;
    }
    # location /media/ {
    #     root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #     try_files               $uri $uri/;
    #     access_log              off;
    #     expires                 30d;
    # }
    location /static/ {
        access_log              off;
        expires                 30d;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        return                  204;
        access_log              off;
        log_not_found           off;
    }

    # error_page  404              /404.html;

    # error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    # location = /50x.html {
    #     root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # }
    }


    gzip_vary                       on;
    gzip_proxied                    any;
    gzip_comp_level                 6;
    gzip_buffers                    16 8k;
    gzip_http_version               1.1;
    gzip_types                      text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
    ssl_ciphers                     "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305";
    ssl_ecdh_curve                  secp384r1;
    ssl_dhparam                     /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout             24h;
    ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:12m;
    ssl_session_tickets             off;
    ssl_stapling                    on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare_origin_ecc.pem;
    ssl_stapling_verify             on;
    resolver                        8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout                5s;


    server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;


    ssl_client_certificate          /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client               on;


    server_tokens                   off;
    charset                         utf-8;
    add_header                      X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header                      Warning 'This computer system including all related equipment, network devices (specifically including Internet access), are provided only for authorized use. Unauthorized use may subject you to criminal prosecution. By accessing this system, you have agreed to the term and condition of use and your actions will be monitored and recorded.';
```

Deploying with this config cause 525 Error: SSL handshake failed. 
I have dedicated IP and NSI. I'm using chacha-poly ciphers. I'm publishing 443 port.

Any thoughts why i'm getting this error?

Thanks

Disclaimer: Stackoverflow, please remove the warning about too much code and not enough text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, replacing OpenSSL with LibreSSL solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the record is gray clouded (not proxied through Cloudflare) are you able to connect to the server using SSL? It's likely an issue on the origin server int he config, but eliminating Cloudflare at least temporarily makes troubleshooting easier.

You can also try curl -Ikv --resolve panel.backupner.com:443:your.ip.address https:://panel.backupner.com for additional details which may be helpful in troubleshooting.

Actually just checked... looks like your site is working now, if you figured out the root cause it would be helpful to post what the issue was. :)

Comment: Eh.. i forgot to remove my domain from code, hehe :) Actually the solution was replacing OpenSSL with LibreSSL and it worked out. I would need to submit support case to get some information about that error, but.. not this time :)